# perl find and replace a part of the matching string (regex issue)

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a huge xml file that contains a bunch of information including email addresses. So all email addresses will be something like the following:

*user*@gmail.com

The issue I'm running into deals with regular expressions. How do i match on the email address but only replace the *user* portion? I tried using look ahead anchors with no luck, (it ends up replacing EVERYTHING before the @gmail.com) Is there a way to use look-ahead but only up to the white-space before user? Or is there a simple solution to this? Right now I have something like the following:

perl 's/(?=@gmail.com)/replacement$&/ge' file.xml

which doesn't work obviously. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand, you want to replace the user portion, but your example, it is everthing before @gmail.com

Comment: what I want to do is just replace the user portion. In my example I said it is wrong, that is just what I have at the moment.

Comment: please add a correct example, sorry I'm still unclear about what you want to achieve

Comment: if i give you a file, and in this file there is a string "user@gmail.com" I would like to replace "user" with some other string. I can't add a correct example because I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a character class that takes all except whitespaces and @:

```
s/[^\s@]+(?=@gmail\.com)/replacement/g
```

Comment: this ends up replacing the "gmail" text and not the "user" portion before @gmail.com

Comment: Please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/lT0tT4/1. It looks working, it replaces the user part. Or, provide us with your input data.

Comment: this ended up giving what i needed thanks!! (I had to also escape the @ in order for it to work)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use the html5 email validator to get the user name.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address

```
$string =~ s/[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*)/$1/g;
```

Expanded:

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
 (                                      # (1 start)
      @
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      (?:
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      )?
      (?:
           \. 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
           (?:
                [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
                [a-zA-Z0-9] 
           )?
      )*
 )                                      # (1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/ (\S+)@gmail\.com/replacement string/g;
```

I think this will resolve your problem for this scenario

```
<email>this is user@gmail.com</email>
```

This regex

```
s/([^>]+)@gmail\.com/replacement string/g
```

will resolve this scenario

```
<email>user@gmail.com</email>
```

And this

```
s/([^"]+)@gmail\.com/replacement string/g
```

will resolve this

```
<person email="user@gmail.com"></person>
```

So combined, we have

```
s/(\S+|[^>]+|[^"]+)@gmail\.com/replacement string/g
```

Comment: if there is only 1 string to be expected you don't need the g flag in the regex